# React native iOS project not run after disconnected from Xcode build in physical device

Tags: react-native, build, react-native-ios

When I first run my project from Xcode in iOS physical device, it work fine. But if I stop the project from Xcode and again start the application from the device, it shows the Splash screen and than quit. I don't understand what is going wrong on the second time.

In both of the cases I am on the same network.

Comment: did you use jsCodeLocation =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"]; in Appdelegate ?

Comment: Yes, For debug build, I used the above URL location.

Comment: @AadityaPaliwal did you find a solution for this problem? We are experiencing right now

Comment: Nope. I have to re-launch the app from Xcode.